# MySQL - SELECT all columns WHERE one column is DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm very sorry if the question seems too basic.
I've surfed entire Internet and StackOverflow for a finished solution, and did not find anything that I can understand, and can't write it myself, so have to ask it here.

I have a MySQL database.
It has a table named "posted".
It has 8 columns.

I need to output this result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT link FROM posted WHERE ad='$key' ORDER BY day, month
```

But I need not only the "link" column, but also other columns for this row.
Like for every row returned with this query I also need to know its "id" in the table, "day" and "month" values etc.

Please tell me what should I read to make it, or how to make it.
Please keep it as simple as possible, as I'm not an expert in MySQL.

Edit:
I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT link,id,day,month FROM posted WHERE ad='$key' ORDER BY day, month
```

It doesn't work. It returns too many rows. Say there are 10 rows with same links, but different day/month/id. This script will return all 10, and I want only the first one (for this link).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish. If you `DISTINCT link`, value of other columns are vague. You can't just select other columns. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: You CAN just select other vague columns if you want a single, arbitrary entry having that description.  Example: Pick a lottery winner; pull a processing entry from a pool; etc.  OP is precise.

Answer (score 107):

The problem comes from instinctively believing that `DISTINCT` is a local pre-modifier for a column.

Hence, you *"should"* be able to type

`XXbadXX SELECT col1, DISTINCT col2 FROM mytable XXbadXX`

and have it return unique values for `col`2.  **Sadly, no.**  `DISTINCT` is actually a global post-modifier for `SELECT`, that is, as opposed to `SELECT ALL` (returning all answers) it is `SELECT DISTINCT` (returning all unique answers).  So a single `DISTINCT` acts on ALL the columns that you give it.

This makes it real hard to use `DISTINCT` on a single column, while getting the other columns, without doing major extremely ugly backflips.

The correct answer is to use a `GROUP BY` on the columns that you want to have unique answers:  **`SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable GROUP BY col2`**  will give you arbitrary unique `col2` rows, with their `col1` data as well.

Comment: How do you determine whether you get the first row of the column that is unique or the last row of the column that is unique?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai:  Please kindly read the manual.  SELECT returns ALL rows that match its query.  Order can be random and is never guaranteed; use an ORDER BY clause if you need otherwise.  See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order).  Good luck.

Comment: so unclear to give such prominence to the wrong way to do it then to stick the correct answer within a paragraph at the bottom.

Answer (score 10):

> I tried this:
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT link,id,day,month FROM posted
>      WHERE ad='$key' ORDER BY day, month
> ```
>
> It doesn't work. It returns too many rows. Say there are 10 rows with
>   same links, but different day/month/id. This script will return all
>   10, and I want only the first one (for this link).

What you're asking doesn't make sense.

Either you want the distinct value of all of `link, id, day, month`, or you need to find a criterion to choose which of the values of `id, day, month` you want to use, if you just want at most one distinct value of `link`.

Otherwise, what you're after is similar to [MySQL's hidden columns in `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), which is non-standard SQL, and can actually be quite confusing.

You could in fact use a `GROUP BY link` if it made sense to pick any row for a given `link` value.

Alternatively, you could use a sub-select to pick the row with the minimal `id` for a each `link` value (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2739528/372643)):

```
 SELECT link, id, day, month FROM posted
     WHERE (link, id) IN
           (SELECT link, MIN(id) FROM posted ad='$key' GROUP BY link)
```

Comment: Awesome, man! I'm surprised there's not a better way to do such a common operation in MySQL. 

In Postgres, we have `DISTINCT ON (...)` that accomplishes this nicely.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Id, Link, Day, Month FROM Posted
WHERE Id IN(
   SELECT Min(Id) FROM Posted GROUP BY Link)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  SELECT OTHER_COLUMNS FROM posted WHERE link in (
  SELECT DISTINCT link FROM posted WHERE ad='$key' )
  ORDER BY day, month
```

Answer (score 3):

If what your asking is to only show rows that have 1 link for them then you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM posted WHERE link NOT IN 
(SELECT link FROM posted GROUP BY link HAVING COUNT(LINK) > 1)
```

Again this is assuming that you want to cut out anything that has a duplicate link.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution would be to do a subquery and then join that to the table. The sub query would return the primary key of the table. Here is an example:

```
select *
from (
          SELECT row_number() over(partition by link order by day, month) row_id
          , *

          FROM posted 
          WHERE ad='$key' 
          ) x
where x.row_id = 1
```

What this does is the row_number function puts a numerical sequence partitioned by each distinct link that results in the query.

By taking only those row_numbers that = 1, then you only return 1 row for each link.

The way you change what link gets marked "1" is through the order-by clause in the row_number function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT link,id,day,month FROM posted WHERE ad='$key' ORDER BY day, month
```

OR

```
SELECT link,id,day,month FROM posted WHERE ad='$key' ORDER BY day, month
```

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem. It returns distinct _combinations_ of all the rows. The Asker wanted to display all columns but only distinct values of one of those columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all columns where link is unique:

```
SELECT * FROM posted WHERE link in
     (SELECT link FROM posted WHERE ad='$key' GROUP BY link);
```

Comment: This returns all the rows in `posted`, not just the one's where `link` is unique. I think it's because your `GROUP BY` is cancelled by the `IN`, which returns duplicates as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posted WHERE ad='$key' GROUP BY link ORDER BY day, month
```

if there are 4 rows for example where link is the same, it will pick only one (I asume the first one).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, maybe that help someone, for example - table with 3 columns

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable WHERE Data_text = 'test' GROUP BY Data_Name ORDER BY Data_Name ASC
```

or

```
SELECT Data_Id, Data_Text, Data_Name FROM DataTable WHERE Data_text = 'test' GROUP BY Data_Name ORDER BY Data_Name ASC
```

Two ways work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can simply use "group by". Below will select ALL, with a DISTINCT "col"

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
GROUP BY col
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* FROM orders a INNER JOIN (SELECT course,MAX(id) as id FROM orders WHERE admission_id=".$id." GROUP BY course ) AS b ON a.course = b.course AND a.id = b.id
```

With the Above Query you will get unique records with where condition

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: Also, this question has already been answered very well. Why you are trying to answer a old question. OP may not have accepted answer, but has been up voted many times. I would suggest you to find new questions to improve upon skills

Answer (score -2):

Select the datecolumn of month so that u can get only one row per link, e.g.:

```
select link, min(datecolumn) from posted WHERE ad='$key' ORDER BY day, month
```

Good luck............

Or

u if you have date column as timestamp convert the format to date and perform distinct on link so that you can get distinct link values based on date instead datetime