# SELECT all Values from a row with distinct values from a column

Tags: php, select, mysqli, phpmyadmin, distinct

id    |    order_id    |    tracking    |    status    |    update_time

---

Table Name : **ndc**

---

1    **100204835**    124124304    0        2017-06-29 00:00:00

2    **100204874**    124104482    0        2017-06-29 00:00:00

3    **100204835**    124124304    0        2017-06-29 00:00:00

---

I need to SELECT all values (**id,order_id,tracking_no**) from **ndc** where **order_id** should be ***unique*** as there might be duplicate values.

> **The result should output all values in the row** as I need to use them further.

For Ex. In the above table order_id 100204835 is duplicate.

Comment: try `DISTINCT` after SELECT. Example: `SELECT *, DISTINCT order_id FROM table`

Comment: but that depends if you want data of a single row regardless of importance of second data of second row

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `Select * from ndc group by order_id;`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Select * from table group by order_id;
```

Comment: This Doesn't work!  It lists 2 rows if their are two same order_id

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT order_id,id,tracking_no FROM ndc;

> also you can use it for distinct on multiple column

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_id  FROM ndc
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT id  FROM ndc
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT tracking_no FROM ndc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DISTINCT with a field name and specifying other fields.

SQL: `SELECT DISTINCT order_id, id,tracking,status,update_time FROM table`

For more continent answer please follow- 
[MySQL - SELECT all columns WHERE one column is DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641270/mysql-select-all-columns-where-one-column-is-distinct)

Answer (score 0):

> **QUERY:**

```
  SELECT id,order_id,tracking_no,status,update_time, DISTINCT order_id FROM ndc;
```

**or** You Can Use Simple `group by order_id;`

**Syntax:** `select * from table_name group by field_name;`

> **NOTE:**  A `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` usually generate the same query plan, so performance should be the same across both query constructs.

Comment: No, this is even listing duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

none of the answers worked for me so here is one that i got working. use group bu on col4 while taking max values of other columns

```
select max(col1) as col1,max(col2) as col2,max(col3) as col3
  , col4
  from 
    table1
  group by col4
```