# Distinct query not working

Tags: mysql, unique, distinct

I've got a table like this *(simplified)*:

`table t`
PostID --- Userid --- Length

PostID is unique, but the Userid isn't. A user may make several posts.
Now I wanted to create a ranklist of the longest Posts and did it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Userid), PostID FROM table t ORDER BY `Length` desc LIMIT 10
```

But this also gives me results like this:
`PostID`--- `Userid` --- `Length`
1 --- **100** --- 3,203
15 --- 942 --- 3,194
45 --- **100** --- 2,093

So a user made two posts that would be ranked. But I thought I avoid those duplicates with the DISTINCT-clause?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I wanted to create a list of the longest posts" - well, you've done this exactly. Do you want to create a list of the longests posts but only allow 1 per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like logically you really don't want to do the DISTINCT since you are just looking to order by longest posts.

Don't you really just want to get the longest posts and sometimes the same user will be in the list multiple times?

```
SELECT Userid, PostID FROM table t ORDER BY `Length` desc LIMIT 10
```

The reason your distinct isn't working is because you are also returning PostID.  If you remove PostID then you will get a distinct UserID.

To do what I think you want you will need to do a subquery as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552192/select-distinct-column-along-with-some-other-columns-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is eliminating duplicate *rows* from the result. The two rows that have a Userid of 100 are not duplicates as the values in the other columns differ.