# MySQL SELECT Distinct on single column not entire query

Tags: mysql

On this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552192/select-distinct-column-along-with-some-other-columns-in-mysql) the user is querying on id to display other columns in the select but query only distinct on a single column.  I've tried to do this but can't get the syntax right.  Here is the query but I only want distinct on `DevelopmentDisplay` column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
`RESI`.`DevelopmentDisplay`,
`RESI`.`City`,
`RESI`.`ZipCode`
FROM
`RESI`
WHERE
`RESI`.`ZipCode` =  '91263'
ORDER BY
`RESI`.`DevelopmentDisplay` ASC
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Select distinct but return all columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-select-distinct-but-return-all-columns)

Comment: I don't want to select * though, there are over 75 columns, I only need a handful of columns.

Comment: So you specify your columns instead of using `*` and still use `GROUP BY` at the end instead of `DISTINCT` in your select

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco why not join the tables with a (SELECT DISTINCT DevelopmentDisplay FROM RESI) T2 ?

Comment: nah, no such luck.  I return 24 results with my query and over a 1000 when I use Group BY...its not the same.

Comment: @Rogier that sound compelling, can you provide an example of what you mean?  can you join a table on itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can self join tables.

I see two options like this. However i would suggest you index DevelopmentDisplay column. Depending on the number of records it can get very slow.

```
SELECT 
    t1.DevelopmentDisplay,
    t1.City,
    t1.ZipCode
FROM
    RESI t1,
    (SELECT DISTINCT DevelopmentDisplay FROM RESI) t2

WHERE
    t1.ZipCode =  '91263' AND
    t1.DevelopmentDisplay = t2.DevelopmentDisplay;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT 
    t1.DevelopmentDisplay,
    t1.City,
    t1.ZipCode
FROM
    RESI t1,
WHERE
    t1.ZipCode =  '91263' AND
    t1.DevelopmentDisplay IN (SELECT DISTINCT DevelopmentDisplay FROM RESI);
```