# PHP7 / mySQL query with DISTINCT plus showing the other columns in $row

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, php-7

I have the following `file_tbl` table:
id  fname   fdescription    ftype   fsize   wbsid   timestamp

And I do no not want to select duplicate rows with same fname and wbsid, but same fname and different wbsid shall be selected.

my query:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(fname), wbsid from file_tbl ORDER BY wbsid ASC");
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo'<hr>file-name:'.$row['fname'];
    echo'<br>file-description:'.$row['fdescription'];
    echo'<br>file-wbs-id:'.$row['wbsid'];
    echo'<br>file-wbs-id:'.$row['timestamp'];
    }
```

- This will cause a Notice: Undefined index: fdescription, timestamp in ... on
  line ...

**the query is working for the distinct, but I need all the columns to be fetched - and I do not know how to SELECT all of them without destroying the query.**
(I made a lot trials with JOIN and GROUP BY, but nothing worked for me - eg this solution does not meet my requirements: 
[Select distinct column along with some other columns in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552192/select-distinct-column-along-with-some-other-columns-in-mysql))

notice: I created the timestamp via PHP , its a (varchar) if this is of any interest.

My approach now is to bring two SELECT queries from the same table together - unfortunately I wasn't able to accomplish this yet. (INNER JOIN; LEFT JOIN; some sorts of subqueries (http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php) ...

edit: a working sql-fiddle is now available -  its working fine there, but not on my own LAMP-stack:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95bad/1
or, the copy-pasted original with InnoDB and latin1:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3bce0/2

Comment: `SELECT * FROM file_tbl ft GROUP BY ft.wbsid ORDER BY ft.wbsid ASC` is not enough?

Comment: @Sepultura : "SELECT * FROM file_tbl ft GROUP BY ft.wbsid ORDER BY ft.wbsid ASC" is not working at all - it would technically work with ft.id instead ft.wbsid - but has not the result i need here... (btw: the wbsid is not a number (int), its a varchar with IP-comperable-format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a column (`fdescription`) which you didn't select.

Try to add `fdescription` to your SELECT clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fname), wbsid, fdescription
FROM file_tbl
ORDER BY wbsid ASC
```

If this does not produce the results you want, try to use grouping:

```
SELECT fname, wbsid, fdescription
FROM file_tbl
GROUP BY fname, wbsid
ORDER BY wbsid ASC
```

Comment: :...
Unfortunately, if I add the columns I need to the SELECT DISTINCT, no filtering out of the duplicates is the result.
And if I try the GROUP BY fname, wbsid the query selects nothing

Comment: The reason, why the SELECT DISTINCT try fails seems to be the 'timestamp' column. if I add it -> never a duplicate -> SELECTS all is the result. (I did not mention the timestamp-column, sorry)

Comment: Since you dont use the timestamp column in query its not the case. Distinct is also eliminates duplicate records for selected columns. Can you create the scenario on sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

edigu's answer seems to offer the correct query for me - unfortunately only in sqlfiddle, and not within my own LAMP stack with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS | Apache/2.4.18 | MySQL 5.7.11-0ubuntu6  | PHP7.0.8-0Ubuntu0.16.04.3

here is the working result, based on edigu's GROUP BY suggestion:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/335584/5

the 2nd and 3rd rows are filtered out (same fname, same wbsid of the data) - just the way it should!

... now, i need to figure-out why its not working on my own installation...

**AND I FOUND OUT:**
The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, and NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION. 
source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Solution:

1.sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Add the following 2 lines of code at the end of the my.cnf (even if most of configuration content is now (Ubuntu 16.) elswhere & only linked herein):

[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

2. sudo service mysql restart

Solution can be found here, too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37248560/4747545